# Users removed from Scheduled reports

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Kindly suggest how to remove any users removed from Scheduled reports.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to reports and open your report - and in the "Run Report" Button, there you have to choose "Schedule Future Runs..."
This will open the already configured schedule for this report and here you can find the configuration "E-Mail Report" where users can be added and deleted for receiving this report.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Find the scheduled report on the scheduled jobs using the time at which the reports are getting delivered.
Step 2: Check which user has scheduled the report.
Step 3: Login into salesforce as the user who have scheduled the report.
Step 4: Go to reports - > open the necessary report - > Subscribe -> Edit recipients - > remove the user.
Step 5: Save the changes.